# passing an Object to Timer

Tags: javascript, timer

how can I pass the RRR object to the timer?

```
function pageReady()
{
var RRR=document.getElementsByClassName("gift-overlay").item(0);
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
}

function myTimer() {
alert(RRR.childNodes.item(26).innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it *global*

```
var RRR;
function pageReady()
{
   RRR=document.getElementsByClassName("gift-overlay").item(0);
  var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
}

function myTimer() {
    alert(RRR.childNodes.item(26).innerHTML);
}
```

or *pass it*

```
function pageReady()
{
var RRR=document.getElementsByClassName("gift-overlay").item(0);
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000,RRR);
}

function myTimer(RRR) {
alert(RRR.childNodes.item(26).innerHTML);
}
```

And please

1. give  proper names to your variables
2. work trough the complete JS DOC before asking questions on SO...

Comment: [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil), [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout): _"Note: Passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and below. If you want to enable this functionality on that browser, you must use a polyfill (see the Polyfill section)."_